# DotNetNuke 6.2.3 Unintended Windows Authentication Login Box

Tags: dotnetnuke-6

My problem is quite easy to be replicated. First, I did a clean installation of DotNetNuke 6.2.3
Selected a Blank Website as template (English)
After done with the installation, I'm now at my Home page which is blank.
Added a new page after "Home"
When I try to access the Page Settings of the newly added page (Admin menu bar -> Pages -> Page Settings), I'll get a DNN Modal PopUp trying to load the Page Settings.
Right after that I get a Windows Authentication Login Box (you know, the small window that reads "Windows Security" if you're using Internet Explorer). I don't remember I enable such feature. I don't know the username and password. I tried entering my windows credential but it's incorrect. After 3 failed attempts, the DNN Modal PopUp stayed there but it's empty.

I've done clean installations on two different machines and ran into the same problem. I don't want this windows authentication login box to appear. I never encounter such problem in previous versions.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 6 painstaking hours, I finally managed to pinpoint the problem. The problem will happen if you name the newly added page as "Reports". Any pages created as children of "Reports" can't be accessed too and will be presented with the Windows Authentication Login Box. I however don't know why we can't name our pages with "Reports"